# Adding a running total column for every inserted value by using Partition by function

Tags: sql-server

If you have better title for this question please let me know. Thank you for your having a look in advance.

Table I have after insert need to update total column

```
FK_Key  Score    Total
----------------------
121       1      NULL
121       5      NULL
121       7      NULL
```

What I want to do is to update the `Total` column by looking at the score values:

```
FK_Key   Score    Total
-----------------------
121        1        1
121        5        6
121        7       13
```

Let's say there is a new row inserted for the same foreign key in the table:

```
121        6       19
```

Every time a new insert happens, it should update the `Total` column summing up the values from the `Score` column grouped by the FK's together - here the `Score` is 19 i.e (1+5+7+6)

Basically I am looking for a update statement that looks through Score column and updates the value for each FK. I don't want the same value updated across all FK's

Here is the query to play with

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Table1') IS NOT NULL 
   DROP TABLE #Table1
GO

CREATE TABLE #Table1
(
    FK_Key INT,
    Score INT NULL,
    Total INT NULL, 
)

INSERT INTO #Table1
VALUES (121, 1, NULL), (121, 5, NULL), (121, 7, NULL), (121, 6, NULL)

SELECT * FROM #Table1
```

Expected result

[image]

Comment: One thought - Could you add in an extra TimeStamp kind of column and then do what you're looking to do via a view rather than insert calculation? Seems it would be a better structure / allow for deletes, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I stated in the comment, my suggestion would be to change the table structure to include a "Timestamp" kind-of column so you know when data was inserted, otherwise, you're not guaranteed of having the exact same recordset returning each time you run your query, then creating a view to get the data you want.

Your solution would look as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1
(
     FK_Key     INT
    ,Score      INT       NULL
    ,InsertTime DATETIME2 DEFAULT GETDATE()
)

INSERT INTO
    #Table1 (FK_Key, Score)
VALUES
    (121, 1), (121, 5), (121, 7), (121, 6)

SELECT
     FK_Key
    ,Score
    -- ,InsertTime
    ,SUM(Score) OVER (PARTITION BY FK_Key ORDER BY InsertTime ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS Total
FROM
    #Table1
```

And, obviously, that last query can just be stored as a view.

This will allow for consistent results and also deal with the situation where rows are deleted after the fact that would mess up your current running total logic.

Hope that makes sense / helps.

Comment: What if i add a Identity column rather than the time stamp. These data is inserted by a SSIS package so it is a mass insert . Timestamp will not help me if data is inserted in chunks.

Comment: Any kind of column that has a uniquely incremental value will work, so `Identity` would be fine.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for the Question title it might help other people

Comment: Maybe "Adding in a running total column" or something along those lines... Don't forget to accept the answer if it worked for you so people know your problem was solved.